# Codeigniter cannot unlink file created by codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I hope someone can help me with this.
I am creating a text file from the query results from a mysql DB. I then set the file to auto download. Once that is done I am trying to unlink the file. It fails to remove the file from the server. When I go to the location and manually try to delete the file it states that it is write protected.

I do not have root access to this system so I can not change the permissions on said file.

Here is the code, is there a way to not create a write protected file?

```
$leagueinfo = $this->livedraft_win_model->get_leagueinfo($sport, $leagueid);
$export = $this->my_model->get_export($sport, $leagueid);
$file_name = $leagueinfo['strat_id'] . '.IOD';
$export=strip_quotes($export);
$export = str_replace(", ",",",$export);
write_file('/tmp/' . $file_name, $export,'x+');
$data = file_get_contents('/tmp/' . $file_name, FILE_BINARY);
ob_clean();
force_download($file_name, $data);
array_map('unlink', glob("/tmp/*.IOD"));
```

I use the same unlink format to remove files that are uploaded to the same location and that works just fine. It is only when I try to remove the files that are created by codeigniter.
Thanks

Comment: Use `chmod()` function after file creation.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code.

```
$this->load->helper("url");
unlink(base_url('/tmp/' . $file_name));
```

Or try this

```
delete_files('/tmp/' . $file_name);
```

For more information please read this doc.

```
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/file_helper.html
```

Comment: I added the following code without any effect.                             chmod('/tmp/*.IOD', 0777);
            force_download($file_name, $data);
            delete_files("/tmp/" . $file_name);

Comment: @Model359 can you please try itt with full path ?

Comment: @Model359 Please try to set "TRUE" in delete_files like "delete_files('./path/to/directory/', TRUE);" as per this doc https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/file_helper.html

Comment: I added the "TRUE" flag and it still doesn't remove the file. I am stuck using the /tmp because that is where I was told to place the files so I can not change the code to use any other location. The owner of the file is apache but that shouldn't matter since it is apache that is writing the file. I changed it to  "delete_files("/tmp/*.IOD", TRUE);"

Comment: @Model359 Did you mean you want to remove "/tmp/" folder from apache server ?

Comment: Nope, I want to delete all the files in /tmp with an IOD extension. I meant I am forced to use /tmp as the location to create the files. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Model359 Can you please try to delete one static file name. i.e "delete_files("/tmp/test.IOD", TRUE);" So we can find out issue is on file extension or in delete_files function.

Comment: Just tried that. I even created a file in /tmp and chmod to 0777 and pointed codeigniter to that file and it still wouldn't delete. It almost looks like it can not find the file, but it is the same format I use to create the file so I do not understand why that could be. Thanks for you help.  I am going to try to figure out the relative path from codeigneiter and see if that works.